# Does a (finite) measure space contain a subset with a desired measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ is a finite measure space. Given any nonnegative real number $c$ with $0<c<\mu(X)$, can we find a subset $A\subset X$ with $\mu(A)=c$?

Is the same assertion true if we assume that $\mu(X)=\infty$ ? If, in general, the answer is negative, what conditions should be imposed on  $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$? For example, is the assertion true for Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Not in general, take $\Sigma = \{ \emptyset, X \}$.

Comment: Continuity of $\mu$ is probably what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as pointed out in the comments, this is not true, in general, since your $\sigma-$algebra may be trivial - i.e. $\{\varnothing,X\}$.

As for the Lebesgue measure, it is indeed true, since $\lambda([0,a])=a$ for any $a>0$, hence the range of the Lebesgue measure is $[0,+\infty]$.

Now, more generally, an interesting category of measures are *non-atomic* measures. In general, if $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space, we say that $\mu$ is non-atomic if for any $A\in\mathcal{A}$ of positive measure, there exists some $B⊆A$, $B\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $0<\mu(B)<\mu(A)$.

It would be a nice excercise to verify that such a measure, when $\mu(X)<\infty$, has the requested property - as a hint, you could at first prove that for any $A\in\mathcal{A}$ of positive measure there exists some $B⊆ A$, $B\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $0<\mu(B)<\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: If we assume that $\mu$ is non-atomic on $(X,\mathcal{A})$, do we still need finiteness condition on $\mu$, that is, do we need $\mu(X)$  to be finite?

Comment: At the moment, I think yes, but I do not have a specific counterexample in mind.